# Problem with flask using Python 3.7.6 with vscode on mac

Tags: python, flask

I have a weird problem with some code I want to run. The code itself should not be the problem since it is downloaded from a Udemy class and not modified:

```
# coding=utf-8
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    items = ["Apfel", "Birne", "Banane"]

    return render_template("start.html", name="Max Mustermann", items=items)

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    name = request.args.get("name")
    return render_template("test.html", name=name)
```

I found online that, to start the emulated webserver(?) I have to rund the following temrinal commands before I can see the output:

> (base) Christophs-MBP:13-23 chris$ export FLASK_APP=run.py run flask 
>   (base) Christophs-MBP:13-23 chris$ export FLASK_APP=run.py run flask 
>   (base) Christophs-MBP:13-23 chris$ export FLASK_APP=run.py 
>   (base) Christophs-MBP:13-23 chris$ run flask 
>   bash: run: command not found 
>   [No reaction to my terminal commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmvZ2.png)

Basically there is no reaction to the command to start the server(?).It should reply with "Running on 127.0.0.1:5000" as soon as I've run the command once.

If I go to my browser, there is no page when I address http://127.0.0.1:5000. What am I doing wrong? I am pretty new to Python and an absolute rookie regarding the terminal. Not sure if I broke something there, since trying to install pyenv to manage my Python installs better as recommended by a friend does not work either (I cannot update the SDK headers as described on [RealPython](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What are the export statements?**

On Mac, `export key=value` creates a new (or updates an existing one) *environment variable* - the tutorial most likely simply asked you to provide one where `key` is `FLASK_APP` and value is a path to your app.

To verify it's been saved correctly, you can list the variables by just typing `export` in the terminal and finding out what's inside each of the environment variables on your system (if you want to only view `FLASK_APP` you can type `export | grep FLASK_APP`).

**Why do you need FLASK_APP?**

When you call `flask run` in your terminal, you will see the following message:

```sh
Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py"
module was not found in the current directory.
```

I presume your file is called `run.py`, therefore none of the conditions are met. You could rename `run.py` to `app.py` and simply type `flask run` in the terminal, but you can also type `export FLASK_APP=<path-to-run.py>`. It seems the tutorial author decided to do the latter. Keep in mind that if you rename your file to `app.py` you will need to run `flask run` within the directory that file lives in. You can change directory in the terminal using `cd` command.

**Why do you get `bash: run: command not found`?**

`bash` is a language running inside your terminal, and it only knows of a few commands - it is not aware of any `run` commands. It does however know about `flask` command once you have installed it on your machine. Within the command's output there is a part which includes a `run` command:

```sh
Commands:
  routes  Show the routes for the app.
  run     Run a development server.
  shell   Run a shell in the app context.
```

Therefore, what you want to do is type `flask run` instead of just `run` in your terminal.

Comment: I had to run the command several times until the FLASK_APP environmental variable was set properly, not sure why. Now it works - thank you very much (especially for the detailed explanation, I hate to just type commands in the terminal without knowing what they do)